# Rhino - how to eval in global context/scope from javascript side only (no Java-side access)

Tags: javascript, rhino

I am working with a third-party application that has a embedded JS scripting environment provided by Mozilla Rhino.

So unfortunately, this means **I have no access to the Java source** or means by which Rhino is configured/embedded in this product.

Bearing this in mind, my goal is to execute an arbitrary quantity of other encoded JS in the global context/scope, using JS and *only* JS. Here's where I'm at (note, this example is somewhat contrived, but bear with me):

```
var engine = new Packages.javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
engine = Packages.javax.script.Invocable(engine);
```

Here's where I'm at. So, I know I can do this:

```
engine.eval("var myVar = \"Hello World!\";");
engine.get("myVar");
=> "Hello World!"
```

But what I want is as if the eval had somehow executed the encoded string within the "current" global context/scope. I.e. so that I can do this:

```
engine.eval("var myVar = \"Hello World!\";");
myVar
=> "Hello World!"
```

Another example of desired behaviour:

```
engine.eval("function sayHello(){ return \"Hello Again!\";}var a = \"Apple\";");
sayHello();
=> "Hello Again!"
a
=> "Apple"
```

I note there are some overloaded eval methods that might be useful:

```
class java.lang.Object eval(java.lang.String,javax.script.Bindings)
class java.lang.Object eval(java.lang.String,javax.script.ScriptContext)
```

However, my extended experiments haven't yet met with any success.

Any thoughts and ideas much greatly appreciated...